# How to publish wsdl when using different endpoints in proxy with WSO2?

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a few send mediators for different web services in proxy:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="DenemeProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="MY_SOAP_ACTION"
                   expression="get-property('Action')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <switch source="get-property('MY_SOAP_ACTION')">
            <case regex="add">
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:12080/SRV_DBS_MOCK/MockGTHBService/MockGTHBService?wsdl"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </case>
            <case regex="sgrsControlInspection">
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://95.0.160.252:19010/CSBWebService?wsdl"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </case>
         </switch>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

I want to publish a wsdl address to clients. But, I use different endpoints as you see. I must publish only allowable methods from these web services. 
How can I publish a wsdl address with allowable methods for this proxy? Must I write a custom wsdl? If so, then how can I write or generate the wsdl?